# deleted every thing from android phone redmi 3s through twrp now phone can't boot

Tags: android

i was installing a rom.I have installed TWRP software and accidentally i have selected all check boxes at the time of wiping the data.It deleted phones system and recovery .Now  my phone can't boot it remains on mi logo . It is not detectable by usb , and volume + power key is also not working it just restarts the phone and again mi logo comes up. what should i do now  make my phone work again. please help

Comment: You cannot remove recovery from twrp. Try to boot into twrp.

Comment: @SanyamJain how should i do that . cause my phone stuck on logo and when i press volume up and power button it just restarts again and again stuck on  mi logo

Comment: Try Volume Down + Power and see if you can go into fastboot mode.

Comment: @SanyamJain  no i cant it do the same restart again and stuck on logo

Comment: Try. You cannot remove fastboot mode ;)

Comment: @SanyamJain  what should i do as it is not coming ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137236/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-sanyam-jain).

Comment: rsolved the issue